# Problems with Azure Key Vault Access Policies when running Terraform Apply

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

When Terraform apply runs, in two scenarios the following happens With Key Vault.

When run from a pipeline through the Service Principle, it will apply the service principle only access policies for Key Vault.

When run from the cmd line, it will only apply the Tenant User Ad access policies for Key Vault.

I need it to do both, as I have devs that want to view the secrets generated in Kay Vault when it goes live. When run through the pipeline only the Service Principle has access to do that.

Back ground info on State File:

The State file sits in Azure and can be accessed from the pipeline service principle and the cmd line when running the following command:  `terraform init -backend-config=/DevOpsProject/Terraform/azure.conf`

The code for Key Vault:

```html
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azuread_service_principal" "current" {
  object_id = "VALUE" // This will need changing per tenant used for KeyVault
}

// This gets the Azure AD Tenant ID information to deploy for KeyVault. 
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "nscsecrets" {
  name                       = "${var.key_vault_name}-${random_string.myrandom.id}"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.location
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  purge_protection_enabled   = true  

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "client" { // This is for AD Users Logged into Azure to give them the right access when creating resources. 
  key_vault_id        = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  secret_permissions  = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions     = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "service_principal" { // This is for the Service Principal in the pipeline to be able to make changes to Key Vault. 
  key_vault_id        = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = data.azuread_service_principal.current.object_id
  secret_permissions  = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions     = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "website_accesspolicy" {
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id          = azurerm_app_service.website_app.identity[0].tenant_id
  object_id          = azurerm_app_service.website_app.identity[0].principal_id
  secret_permissions = ["get"]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "website_logs_storage_accesspolicy" { // This is for the Storage Account for Website Logs. 
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id          = azurerm_storage_account.website_log_storage.identity[0].principal_id
  key_permissions    = ["get", "create", "delete", "list", "restore", "recover", "unwrapkey", "wrapkey", "purge", "encrypt", "decrypt", "sign", "verify", ]
  secret_permissions = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "website_logs_key" {
  name         = "website-logs-key"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id

  key_type = "RSA"
  key_size = 2048
  key_opts = ["decrypt", "encrypt", "sign", "unwrapKey", "verify", "wrapKey", ]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.website_logs_storage_accesspolicy
  ]

}
```

Comment: hello @Jason, may i know if you have you tried using data for azuread users just as you are doing for service principal and then using the object id for the user to set the access policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the pipeline you must be authenticating to azure using the service principal.

To add the **User** and **Service Principal** both to the access policy of the keyvault. Instead of using data source for `azuread_service_principal` you should use data source for `azuread_user` as you are authenticating via service principal the data source `azurerm_client_config` will have the objectId of the service principal. So , your code will be something like below `(I tested this by authenticating via service principal from local)`:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "88073b30-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-8442c93573ae"
    tenant_id = "ab078f81-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-620b694ded30"
    client_id = "7f1a4457-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-293b51794fb3"
    client_secret = "aGY7Q~0n2iKMOxxxxxxxxxxxxlnNG9Pnt2k"
    features {}
}
provider "azuread"{
    tenant_id = "ab078f81-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-620b694ded30"
    client_id = "7f1a4457-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-293b51794fb3"
    client_secret = "aGY7Q~0n2iKMOxxxxxxxxxxxxlnNG9Pnt2k"
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
// This gets the Azure AD Tenant ID information to deploy for KeyVault and also contains the service principal objectID.
data "azurerm_resource_group" "Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform"{
    name = "ansuman-resourcegroup"
}
// user which I want to give permissions to be able to access the keyvault.
data "azuread_user" "user"{
user_principal_name = "ansuman@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
}
 
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "nscsecrets" {
  name                       = "Ansumankeyvault0123456"
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.name
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform.location
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  purge_protection_enabled   = true  

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "client" { // This is for AD Users Logged into Azure to give them the right access when creating resources. 
  key_vault_id        = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = data.azuread_user.user.object_id
  secret_permissions  = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions     = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "service_principal" { // This is for the Service Principal in the pipeline to be able to make changes to Key Vault. 
  key_vault_id        = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  secret_permissions  = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions     = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

Please make sure the Service principal you are using has the below API permissions granted with admin consent for that tenant:

[image]

Comment: Hi after testing the pipeline it never added in my user account to the Key Vault. Also when manually running Terraform its still just adding the user not the service principle. 

I basically still have the same issue.

Comment: hello @Jason, may i know how you are authenticating to azure via terraform?

Comment: I sorted it now its because I was also adding in a Secret and the Secret did not have the right permissions.